# How can I copy/clone objects(reference type) without using IClonable in C#?

Tags: c#, object, copy, clone

I don't want to **assign properties one by one**. Please do not say, I need to assign 1 by 1. I know **IClonable interface** but unfortunately, suppose that Point class **comes from other library , so I can not modify.** How can I achieve cloning object which belongs to other libraries?

In below example, as expected  when we change p2, p1 is changed as well. My aim is copying p1, and when I change copy object, I do not want main object to change. Int his example, I want p1 to keep as it was before.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        Point p1 = new Point(5,6);
        Point p2= p1;

        p2.X = 9;

        Console.WriteLine("x={0}, y={1}", p1.X, p1.Y);
    }

    class Point 
    {
       // Constructor:
       public Point(int x, int y)
       {
          X = x;
          Y = y;
       }

       // Property implementation:
       public int X { get; set; }

       public int Y { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `MemberwiseClone` method inherited from `System.Object`:

```cs
public Point ShallowClone()
{
   return (Point)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

`ICloneable` is an interface, not a class. Whether you implement `ICloneable` or not makes no difference regarding the assignment of  properties one by one or not.

---

Other options:

- If you have not access to the code of `Point` or cannot derive your implementation from it:

  - Use the [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/) NuGet package (or one of the various other ones).
  - Create an extension method.
- Make the class immutable. Like this you can just copy the reference around just as with strings.
- Implement `Point` as a struct. Structs can be copied by simple assignment.
- Implement `Point` as a class or struct `record` which automatically provides value behavior (immutability, value equality) and much more. See: [Records (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record).

Comment: good answer but I can not modify  Point  class, so just opiton will be create an extension method? How? and may I use  shallowClone?  I need deepClone , I think

Comment: Your example class suggests that you need only a shallow clone (two `int` properties). A deep clone applies only when an object has references to other objects and is not a trivial thing to implement. I suggest not reinventing the wheel and instead use an existing mapper.

Comment: In my real senario, I have nested classes. What do you mean by existing mapper? Automapper? and can automapper works for deepcopy?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.nuget.org/packages/DeepCloner

Comment: I can just use auto mapper, not other nuget pagckages because of company restrictions

Comment: See: [Create Deep Copies Of Object In C# Using AutoMapper](https://jshowers.com/create-deep-copies-of-object-in-c-using-automapper/).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the object and use I have serialized and deserialized. Probably not appropriate for all situations.

```
var obj2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ObjType>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out this problem with using automapper .

You can check my solution:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/En51IP   (using new way )

https://dotnetfiddle.net/iapj84   (using old way )

Answer (score 0):

I did like this:

```
public UpdateVisitor(HttpRequest request)
{
    HttpRequest m_Request;
    m_Request = request as Object as HttpRequest;
    if (request.Equals(m_Request))
    {
        throw new Exception("None cloning happend");
    }
    // Start a worker thread that uses m_request
    UpdateVisitorWorker(m_request);
}
```

No exception raised!